# How to install PyGObject in Anaconda on linux?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, anaconda, pygobject, python-3.7

When importing PyGObject in my Anaconda Python3.7 installation,

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

I get following error message:

```
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

I installed pygobject and gobject-introspection from the conda-forge channel.

When I use the system installation of Python it works just fine.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Libosinfo, @felixinho did you find any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably missing gtk3. This is what you have to do to make your snippet work:

- install [PyGObject](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygobject):
  `conda install -c conda-forge pygobject`
- install [Gtk3](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gtk3):
  `conda install -c conda-forge gtk3`